# Join two tables by address matching

Tags: python, pandas, textmatching

I want to merge two tables by approximate matching of addresses. One table has 10000 addresses and the other has 33000 addresses.

[image: First table]

[image: Second table]

And then, extract 'Property ID' for each address in first table. How should I do that?

I used

```
import difflib
add['Property Address'] = add['Property Address'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, address['Address']))
```

But, this gives me an error. Plus, the code takes hours to run. Any method to improve efficiency?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide the data in text form , png is not worth to reproduce the example.

Comment: I used difflib.get_close_matches() but it doesn't work. import difflib
add['Property Address'] = add['Property Address'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, address['Address']))

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code and this is more of an algorithm question:

I would break the addresses into number, street, city, zip, state. [Trim all values, set to upper or lower case.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) Then create a routine that creates a weighted value for each match and near match based on the Levenshtein distance. The weight is a tuning parameter between 0 and 1 but the total of all weights should be 1.  Return a weight (match probability and have your program copy the resulting few fields using a list comprehension or itterrow. The tables aren't that big, so optimization shouldn't be an issue.  You could also do this using a dictionary - see [David Beasley's talk](https://www.dabeaz.com/tutorials.html#Learn%20Python%20Through%20Public%20Data%20Hacking) on that.  Lots of examples if you search this site.

Comment: Yeah, but with 10000 rows in one table and 30000 in other, this would become computationally very slow. I used difflib.get_close_matches() and takes hours of computation.